# Month between two dates

Tags: sql, oracle, date, between

I want to join when

I have the below two tables and I want to join when the Month column is between the first day of the start_dt month and end_dt

tableA

```
id     start_dt        end_dt
1      1/10/2018      12/31/9999
1      02/01/2018     12/31/9999
```

tableB

```
id    Month
1    1/1/2018
```

Below syntax but I'm receiving errors on both attempts

```
LEFT JOIN id = id AND A.MONTH = TRUNC(AHR2.START_DT,'MM') AND AHR2.END_DT
   --ERROR NOT A VALID MONTH
--LEFT JOIN id = id AND TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(A.MONTH, 'DD/MM/YYYY'),'YYYYMM') BETWEEN TO_CHAR(AHR2.START_DT,'YYYYMM') AND AHR2.END_DT
   --ERROR LITERAL DOES NOT MATCH FORMAT STRING
```

Expected Results:

```
id  Month          Start_dt            end_dt
1   01/01/2018      01/10/2018          12/31/9999
```

Comment: LEFT JOIN AND? Seems very strange.

Comment: Update question wording and syntax

Comment: What is a "Month date"? I know only "date" (i.e. year + month + day + optionally time) or "month" (i.e. name or number from 1..12)

Answer (score 2):

> I want to join when the Month date is between the first day of the start_dt month and end_dt

If that is all you want to do, you could try:

```
select <your fields>
from tableA
left join tableB on tableB.Month BETWEEN tableA.start_dt 
                                     AND tableA.end_dt
```

This joins onto tableB only where the Month Field is between start_dt and end_dt.

**Edit based on OP amending question:**

He states:

> between the first day of the start_dt month

If the start_dt has to be matched only for the first day of the month of the start_dt then this query should work for that.

```
select <your fields>
from tableA
left join tableB on tableB.Month BETWEEN DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, tableA.start_dt), 0) 
                                     AND tableA.end_dt
```

Comment: As `end_dt` is 12/31/9999 `tableB.Month >= tableA.start_dt` should be also sufficient.

Comment: @John Amended answer based on OP's change in question.

Answer (score 0):

does you want to left join between two tables like below

```
select a.* from tabla a left join tableb b on a.id=b.id
where a.Month >=b.start_dt and a.month<=b.end_dt
```

`LEFT JOIN AND` is not valid sql syntax you have to put table name after left join then need `on` for putting join key

Answer (score 0):

Ah, now I see better what you're shooting for... with the tables and description of the problem you provided, this should do what you need. There are a ton of ways to manipulate dates; lots of possible answers to this.  But the goal is that you should be trying to "push" the start_dt back to the first day of its month, then doing your compare. So

```
SELECT * from tableA AHR2
LEFT JOIN tableB B
ON A.ID = B.ID 
  AND B.Month 
   BETWEEN (AHR2.start_dt - (1+ DAYS(AHR2.start_dt)))
           AND 
           AHR2.end_dt
```

or

```
    BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS((LAST_DAY(AHR2.start_dt)+1),-1) 
           AND 
           AHR2.end_dt
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked best for me is the below.

```
LEFT JOIN A.ID = B.ID AND TO_DATE(B.MONTH,'MM/DD/YYYY') BETWEEN TRUNC(A.START_DT,'MM') AND A.END_DT
```